# Largely cartoon story about a girl daydreaming about creating a robotic duplicate, realizing that means she will need to study science

Tags: comics, identification-request

I read this in a grade school reader in Ashland, KY, somewhere between 1986 and 1990, I'm fairly certain. It was in my older brother's book. I remember that the artwork was somewhat sketchily drawn, probably in a limited number of colors. The primary story has a female inventor going on some sort of TV show, talking about having created robot duplicates. Ultimately, it is shown that the "inventor" doing the interview is the duplicate, thereby showing how well it imitates a human. I think it ends with the girl waking from the daydream, realizing that she will have to study the sciences to be able to create such a gynoid. It might have started with a framing story with her saying that she didn't need to study the sciences to do great things.

The story only took a handful of pages in the book, less than ten, but I think at least four.